# Execute a shell script without `./`

Tags: command-line, scripts, sh

I'm learning how to create shell scripts on UNIX for a college class. The textbook says I should just be able to type the filename in my terminal and it should run, but so far I haven't been able to get that to work. But it works fine when I type in `./myscript`.
Currently, I am typing the scripts out on my Mac terminal, but I had FreeBSD loaded onto a virtual box and it was doing the same thing to me.

I think maybe I need to change my environment path? I remember I had to do that when I started writing python files.

Comment: FreeBSD and macOS are not Ubuntu. Please ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Use the full path or put it in ~/bin

Comment: In the past people had `.` in their PATH which means, at some point, if not found elsewhere, the search will be in current directory. Especially for root or any kind of high power user this is a security nightmare about to happen, so it is best not to have it and force users to input the full path name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run scripts you have written yourself you have a couple options.

**OPTION 1**

You can store them in `/usr/bin`.

This is personally what I do as I read somewhere a long time ago that `/usr/bin` was for things exactly like this and I've never really thought of it otherwise

I do however keep a copy of the scripts in a separate folder `Documents/SourceCode/` which is where I do all my editing and testing. then I just copy the script over to `/usr/bin`

**OPTION 2**

You can just store them all in your testing folder so in my case...

`Documents/SourceCode/`

and add this to my path variable.

`export PATH=$(PATH):/home/user/Documents/SourceCode`

Comment: Putting the script in `~/bin` is better than either of those options. Or if for multiple users `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @Panther Arguably it's the preferred method, but option 2 is same as `~/bin`. Difference is that .bashrc on Ubuntu already adds ~/bin to PATH if it exists. I agree with your comment but only partially.

Comment: @Panther thanks for the catch! I am curious though as to what makes `~/bin` "better"?

Comment: With ubuntu,  `~/bin` is on a users path by default and it does not require root powers so it is very simple

Comment: Ah this would explain, I've never had a multi user system so I've never had to worry about anyone else :'D