# Is there any way to make windows batch file like in Linux

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

In Windows CMD I can write some DOS commands in a text file, with `*.bat` extension, then just calling the file name will execute the commands.

`cd c:\myapp
dir`

Saving the above file, for example, `m.bat` will make it executable by entering `m` in the command prompt.

In Linux I tried to wrap the command `service network-manager restart` in a `.sh` file named `rn.sh` after changing its mode `chmod +x rn.sh` to be executable I always have to enter `./rn.sh` to run it.

However, I just need to enter `rn` to run it. In other words, I need that `rn.sh` file works like a program or an application. How could I do that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069554/execute-a-shell-script-without/1069557#1069557

Comment: put it into PATHs and actually you don't need .sh extension, just `mv rn.sh rn` and it will still work. But for the original script, it is better to just use alias.

Comment: @AlvinLiang your comment is a great answer. I copied the file to `~/bin` as you described and it works as a breeze!